# Unable to compile Intel Pin

Tags: c++, ubuntu, intel-pin

I am using intel Pin on a 64 bit ubuntu machine (12.04). I exported the path in the correct way but I am not able to run the pin binary. When I do a "file" on that binary, it shows it is 32bit ELF binary. Is this a problem? I am not able to run the binary even if I run it from the same folder.

The error message I keep getting is `bash: /home/<username>/Downloads/pin-2.14-67254-gcc.4.4.7-linux/pin: No such file or directory`

Could someone please tell me where did I go wrong?

Eidt: I tried adding the i386 architecture so that the 32 bit pin binary would run, but it is not able to execute the 64 bit tool I have written.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists

Comment: Can you write the command you're trying to run and the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

You could run pin.sh rather than pin.
Command like this:

```
sudo ./../../../pin.sh -t obj-intel64/pinatrace.so -- /bin/ls
```

it works with me.